BlazorWebView in Maui cannot click anything
When I use a tabbed page layout and call blazor web view pages in my Shared RCL, none of the buttons work in those pages.
When I use the normal navigation everything works. Am I calling this correctly?
Here is the normal MainPage.Xaml
  <BlazorWebView x:Name="blazorWebView" HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
        <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type local:Components.Routes}" />
        </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
    </BlazorWebView>

Here is my modified MainPage.xaml with a tabbed page. This will show the screens from the Razor Class Library. I just cant interact with any of them(button clicks, Events etc)
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mobile"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
             android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="False"
             x:Class="Mobile.MainPage"
             BarTextColor="White"
             BarBackgroundColor="#2B0B98"
             SelectedTabColor="White"
             UnselectedTabColor="SlateGrey"
             BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Mobile.Components.Pages">

    <ContentPage Title="Home"  IconImageSource="{StaticResource TabOne}">
        <BlazorWebView HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
            <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages:Home}" />
            </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </BlazorWebView>
    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage Title="Scheduler" IconImageSource="{StaticResource TabTwo}">
        <BlazorWebView  HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
            <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages:Scheduler}" />
            </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
        </BlazorWebView>
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Users" IconImageSource="{StaticResource TabThree}">
            <BlazorWebView  HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
                <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                    <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages:UserManagement}" />
                </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            </BlazorWebView>
        </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Messages" IconImageSource="{StaticResource TabFour}">
            <BlazorWebView  HostPage="wwwroot/index.html">
                <BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
                    <RootComponent Selector="#app" ComponentType="{x:Type pages:Messages}" />
                </BlazorWebView.RootComponents>
            </BlazorWebView>
        </ContentPage>

    <pages:Settings IconImageSource="{StaticResource TabFive}"/>
</TabbedPage>


I created a new project with the Maui Blazor project template and added the three pages(home, counter, weather) in a new TabbedPage. I can click on the counter page's counter button. Can you show the details to reproduce the problem?
